# Does cached statement does not allow connection to be terminated?

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I have a application where I am using Hibernate 3.4 and c3p0 0.9.1. I am facing the database connection timeout error.

My Persistence.xml file is

```
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/app?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="XXXXX"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="XXXXX"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
        <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select * from status"/>
        <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true"/>
```

When the application is run and kept idle for 40 - 48 hrs I get database connection timeout error. Earlier I had faced this problem and solved it by adding `hibernate.c3p0.timeout`, `hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period`, `c3p0.preferredTestQuery`, `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout`, & `c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`. And the application was working fine. But now the error has resurfaced.

When I went through the logs on the system where I am getting the error. I noticed following things
1) My initial connection pool is of 5. Which is increasing.
2) Also with the increase in managed connection the GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache is also showing that num connection is increasing with the number of decreasing unused connection.

My question is - if a statement is cached will the c3p0 release the connection back to pool which then can be tested for idle condition and terminated?

`@Update`

Following exception is printed in the log:

```
07 Aug 2013 01:44:18 550134943 [http-8080-7] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection  - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1516432 invalidated by Exception.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 149,249,259 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 149,249,261 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor39.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1971)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1812)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:88)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:104)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.dal.LoginDataManager.authenticateUser(LoginDataManager.java:117)
at zumigo.businesslogic.LoginManager.login(LoginManager.java:46)
at zumigo.servlets.Authentication.processRequest(Authentication.java:124)
at zumigo.servlets.Authentication.doGet(Authentication.java:354)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3333)
... 50 more
07 Aug 2013 01:44:18 550134943 [http-8080-7] WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection  - [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
```

`Update 2`

In the log I see following entry when the tomcat is started - values read from the persistence.xml;

```
properties[
    hibernate.connection.password: neilsoft
    c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout: true
    hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period: 300
    hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
    hibernate.show_sql: true
    hibernate.c3p0.max_statements: 50
    hibernate.c3p0.timeout: 1800
    hibernate.generate_statistics: true
    hibernate.c3p0.min_size: 5
    hibernate.format_sql: true
    hibernate.connection.username: root
    c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces: true
    hibernate.connection.driver_class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    hibernate.cache.provider_class: org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider
    c3p0.preferredTestQuery: select * from status
    hibernate.c3p0.max_size: 20
    hibernate.connection.provider_class: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate.connection.url: jdbc:mysql://10.2.2.236:3306/lbs?autoReconnect=true
]]
```

And c3p0 init value are:

```
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20206 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory  - Initializing connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20207 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://ec2-67-202-10-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/lbs?autoReconnect=true
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20207 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - Connection properties: {user=XXXX, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20207 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider  - autocommit mode: true
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20217 [http-8080-1] INFO  com.mchange.v2.log.MLog  - MLog clients using log4j logging.
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20434 [http-8080-1] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry  - Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20470 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean  - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2zreza8wnzkcdpvnjkja|14c7a98] registered.
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20535 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean  - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2zreza8wnzkcdpvnjkja|14c7a98] unregistered, in order to be reregistered after update.
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20535 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.management.DynamicPooledDataSourceManagerMBean  - MBean: com.mchange.v2.c3p0:type=PooledDataSource[2zreza8wnzkcdpvnjkja|14c7a98] registered.
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20665 [http-8080-1] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource  - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@b5006db1 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@6724e358 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, **debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true**, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 2zreza8wnzkcdpvnjkja|1c7d56b, **idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300**, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, m**axIdleTime -> 1800**, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, **maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50**, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, **minPoolSize -> 5**, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@35a58726 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2zreza8wnzkcdpvnjkja|71949b, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/app?autoReconnect=true, properties -> {user=******, password=******, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} ], **preferredTestQuery -> select * from status**, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, **testConnectionOnCheckout -> true**, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 2zreza8wnzkcdpvnjkja|14c7a98, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20713 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 1
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20713 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 2
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20713 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 3
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20713 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 4
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20713 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - incremented pending_acquires: 5
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20738 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - **com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 config: [start -> 5; min -> 5; max -> 20; inc -> 3; num_acq_attempts -> 30; acq_attempt_delay -> 1000; check_idle_resources_delay -> 300000; mox_resource_age -> 0; max_idle_time -> 1800000; excess_max_idle_time -> 0; destroy_unreturned_resc_time -> 0; expiration_enforcement_delay -> 450000; break_on_acquisition_failure -> false; debug_store_checkout_exceptions -> false]**
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20738 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - acquire test -- pool size: 0; target_pool_size: 5; desired target? 1
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20738 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - awaitAvailable(): [unknown]
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20738 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 0, unused: 0, excluded: 0]
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20782 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20782 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20782 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@320399.acquireResource() returning. 
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20783 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 1, unused: 1, excluded: 0]
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20783 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - decremented pending_acquires: 4
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20784 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - Testing PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f] on CHECKOUT.
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20783 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@320399.acquireResource() returning. 
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20787 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 2, unused: 1, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f)
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20787 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - decremented pending_acquires: 3
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20789 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20790 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@320399.acquireResource() returning. 
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20790 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 3, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f)
07 Aug 2013 01:46:32 20790 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - decremented pending_acquires: 2
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20843 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20843 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - Test of PooledConnection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f] on CHECKOUT has SUCCEEDED.
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20843 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 3, unused: 2, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f)
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20848 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20848 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@320399.acquireResource() returning. 
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20848 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 4, unused: 3, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f)
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20848 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - decremented pending_acquires: 1
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20850 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory  - RDBMS: MySQL, version: 5.1.49-1ubuntu8
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20850 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory  - JDBC driver: MySQL-AB JDBC Driver, version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.16 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20852 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20852 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool  - com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager@320399.acquireResource() returning. 
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20852 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f)
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20852 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - decremented pending_acquires: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20915 [http-8080-1] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  - Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20917 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20918 [http-8080-1] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5e9f1 [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@1ed688f)
07 Aug 2013 01:46:33 20918 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] DEBUG com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache  - checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 0; checked out: 0; num connections: 0; num keys: 0
```

Comment: please show the Exception you are seeing. (to answer your question: statement caching does not prevent release of Connections back to the pool and does not prevent testing or expiration of Connections.)

Comment: Note that the Exception you are seeing is logged at DEBUG level. This is a log of an Exception experienced by a client that c3p0 has "noticed" means the Connection is broken. The Connection will not be allowed back into the pool. All that said, under the settings you've described, your application shouldn't see db-timed-out Connections. Some recommendations: 1) Upgrade to c3p0 0.9.2.1. 0.9.1 is very old. 2) Verify that your config is what you think it is, using JMX or c3p0's dump of config on pool init.

Comment: I have added the c3p0 initialization values from the log file in my question above.

Comment: hi -- you should see a log entry directly from c3p0 @ INFO level on pool init. it's always good to check that, to ensure that, through many layers of wrapper and interface, c3p0 is actually seeing the config you expect to give it. (you can also check by JMX.) the log entry you want should begin with the string "Initializing c3p0 pool..."

Comment: `@SteveWaldman` I wanted to know if I upgrade the c3p0 jar from 0.9.1 to 0.9.2.1 - is there any why to log the trace into the log file for each connections - Request, Execution, Close?

Comment: c3p0 does a lot of logging if you debug at DEBUG / TRACE/ FINEST levels (depending on your log library). it won't log statement contents, generally. there are lots of different loggers, but you might have to log everything under com.mchange first to get a sense of which you want, then restrict only to those.